# AssociationTypeMismatch in ItemsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im creating an online retail store. That has Items that are belongs_to a category. When i try to submit the item with a category selected it wont save

I tried for many hours to fix but can't figure it out. Anyone see what the problem is?

Error is

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ItemsController#create
Category(#70298375791060) expected, got String(#70298372605800)

  def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)
    if @item.save
      redirect_to @item
      flash[:success] = "You have created a new item"
```

Items Form

```
<h1>Create New item</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_form_for @item, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :image%>
            <%= f.collection_select :category, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true, :prompt => "Select One Category" %>
            <%= f.input :title%>
            <%= f.input :price %>
            <%= f.input :description %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create new item", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Items Controller

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user_edit,   only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @item = @user.items.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def home
    @items = Item.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if @item.update(item_params)
       redirect_to @item
       flash[:success] = 'Item was successfully updated.'
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)
    if @item.save
      redirect_to @item
      flash[:success] = "You have created a new item"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Your item didn't save"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Item.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Item deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:title, :category, :price, :description, :image)
    end

    #Check to see if user can edit item.
    def correct_user_edit
      if @item = current_user.items.find_by(id: params[:id])
      else
        flash[:danger] = "You can't edit that item"
        redirect_to root_url if @item.nil?
      end
    end

end
```

Item model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    validates :category, presence: true
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 } 
    validates :price, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 2000 }
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600", medium: "250x250", thumb:"100x100#"}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry
    has_many :items
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ItemsController#create
>   Category(#70298375791060) expected, got String(#70298372605800)

This line

```
<%= f.collection_select :category, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true, :prompt => "Select One Category" %>
```

should be

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true, :prompt => "Select One Category" %>
```

And also change in the the `item_params` as well

```
def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:title, :category_id, :price, :description, :image)
end
```

> undefined method `category_id' for Item:0x007fdf43bebed0

You should have `category_id` column in `items` table. Run the following command which creates a migration file for adding `category_id` to `items`.

```
rails g migration add_category_id_to_items category_id:integer
```

and `run rake db:migrate`

And I suggest you to read these [***Guides***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) before going further.

Comment: Hello. Yes I tried that before. It didnt work. Same Error ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ItemsController#create Category(#70298429729020) expected, got String(#70298372605800)

Comment: @joeyk16 Have tried changing in the `item_params` too?

Comment: Yes i tried that too. My error is now undefined method `category_id' for #<Item:0x007fdf43bebed0>

Comment: @joeyk16 You should have `category_id` column in `items` table. Create a migration and run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: O really. Ok thanks Pavan. You're always helping me out.

Comment: rails g migration add_category_id_to_items category_id:integer worked. Thanks Pavan!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `category`, you should pass `category_id` param.